# OR shows result, AND doesn't show

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following problem, a table as simple as

**PERSON**:

```
FNAME  LNAME  AGE
-----------------
John   Carl   22
Rupert Luis   24
```

If I execute the following T-SQL query:

```
Select * 
from PERSON 
WHERE FNAME = 'John' AND LNAME = 'Carl'
```

It doesn't show any results... and if I place an OR instead of AND it does, to me it makes no sense, but it probably is correct, I just want to understand why so?

Comment: It can happen due to collation or a space caractere you are seeing.

Comment: SELECT len(fname), fname, len(lname), lname and see if there are blanks

Comment: Does this SQL return results for you? - Select * from PERSON WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(FNAME)) = 'John' AND LTRIM(RTRIM(LNAME)) = 'Carl'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that you have shown the data, there is a space at the beginning of the last name.  I don't know if that is true in the original data, but it is true in the query.

Then strings `'CARL'` and `' CARL'` are not the same.  You can do the comparisons as:

```
where ltrim(rtrim(firstname)) = 'John' and ltrim(rtrim(lastname)) = 'Carl'
```

Or you could fix the data:

```
update person
    set lastname = ltrim(rtrim(lastname));
```

Or, there might be another similar problem, typically caused by:

- Hidden characters in the string that don't print (often at the beginning or end).
- Characters that look similar but are different, such as zero and capital-O.

Comment: Those names were just examples, the problem was Luis and Luís. Thanks your answer helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing something wrong with AND OR
As the data appears the AND should return the data

Most likely what you have is data that appears to be the same but is not

Do this to figure out which is missing

```
Select *  
from PERSON  
WHERE FNAME = 'John'

Select * 
from PERSON 
WHERE LNAME = 'Carl'
```

On the one that returns nothing try

```
Select * 
from PERSON 
WHERE LNAME like '%Carl%'
```